# Rails: generate select box for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a select box for a collection. I use method `options_for_select` but It just generates `<option></option>` field, not `<select></select>` outside. 
Here is my code:

```
<% categories_array = Category.all.map{|category| [category.name, category.id]} %>
<%= options_for_select(categories_array) %>
```

And here is the result:

```
<option value="5483c910485559047a000000">Programming</option>
<option value="5483c921485559047a010000">Business</option>
<option value="5483c92b485559047a020000">Game Programming</option>
```

But I expected:

```
<select id = "categoryId">
  <option value="5483c910485559047a000000">Programming</option>
  <option value="5483c921485559047a010000">Business</option>
  <option value="5483c92b485559047a020000">Game Programming</option>
</select>
```

Moreover, I can get this value when publish this form to server. How can I do this

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how select and options helpers are combined here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

As noted there:

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select(...)) %>
```

Comment: thanks :) I want just a little more. In the html code is generated: first `option` with `option`. Is there any way to make it on new line also.? I know this will not affect how program run, but makes me easily to read code and debug later. thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean change the format of the HTML (source) output? There are different options you can try, but as this was a pet peeve of mine for a long time with Rails/ERB/Erubis, in the end it seemed better to abandon hopes of cleanly-formatted output. (Haml is better in this area, but I prefer Erubis.)

Comment: If you need to examine outputted HTML in a more structured way, using Firebug or Firefox/Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the source may be a better option.